# How to remove every second value from a C++ array without making a copy of the array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Problem: I want to get an array `A[6] = {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}` to be `A[6] = {5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1}`. In other words - "delete" every second value starting with 0th and shift all other values to the left.

My Attempt:

To do that I would use this code, where a - length of the relevant part of an array A (the part with elements that are not deleted), ind - index of the value that I want to delete.

```
for (int j = ind; j < n; j++)
    A[j] = A[j+1];
```

However, I couldn't get this to work, using the code like that:

```
void deleting(int A[], int& a, int ind){
    for (int j = ind; j < a; j++)
        A[j] = A[j+1];

    a--;
}

int A[6] = {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
a = 6

for (int i = 0; i < a; i+=2)
    deleting(A, a, i);
```

After running this code I was getting `A[6] = {5, 4, 2, 1, 1507485184, 1507485184}`. So, it deleted the elements at indexes 0, 3. Why did it delete the 3rd index?

Comment: Do you have to use C array? Can't you use vector?

Comment: you cant delete entries from a c-style array. You should either use a `std::vector` or create a new array with the desired elements

Comment: If you delete every 2nd element the resulting array has entries that are meaningless.

Comment: @MarošBeťko sadly I have to use the array - trying to do an assignment for my classes and I am not supposed to know about vectors.

Comment: @Zyberg What is the expected behavior for the second half of the array? Do you care about values in it after the deletion procedure?

Comment: `for (int j = A[ind];` is using an element of the array for the starting index. You should start at `ind`.

Comment: Try using `ind` instead of `A[ind]` in the `for`

Comment: @tobi303 I know that, but by deleting I meant "removing the value that I don't want and shift the array places so that the last element is duplicated". It is practically deletion, if you keep the array's relevant part index. For example: A[3]={1, 2,3} I "delete" 0th element to obtain an array A[3] ={2,3,3}. I removed the 0th element and shifted the places of other elements.

Comment: @Philipp yes, that is how it should be, since it is impossible to really delete values from C++ array.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 I don't care about the second part of the array. It is completely meaningless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. walk the array, copying the last `n-i` elements forward one place for every even `i`, or
2. figure out the eventual state and just go straight to that. The eventual state is the first `n/2` places are `array[i]=array[2*i + 1]`, and the last `n/2` places are just copies of the last element.

The first method is what you asked for, but it does multiple redundant copy operations, which the second avoids.

As for your implementation problems, examine what happens when `j=n-1`, and remember `A[n]` is not a valid element of the array.
I suggest making the copy-everything-forward operation its own function anyway (or you can just use memcpy)

Answer (score 4):

For these kinds of problems (in-place array manipulation), it's a good idea to just keep an index or pointer into the array for where you are "reading" and another where you are "writing."  For example:

```
void odds(int* a, size_t len) {
  int* writep = a;
  int* readp = a + 1;
  while (readp < a + len) { // copy odd elements forward
    *writep++ = *readp;
    readp += 2;
  }
  while (writep < a + len - 1) { // replace rest with last
    *writep++ = a[len - 1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for kicks, here is a version which doesn't use a loop:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
std::ostream& print(std::ostream& out, T const (&array)[Size]) {
    out << "[";
    std::copy(std::begin(array), std::end(array) -1,
              std::ostream_iterator<T>(out, ", "));
    return out << std::end(array)[-1] << "]";
}

template <std::size_t TI, std::size_t FI, typename T, std::size_t Size>
bool assign(T (&array)[Size]) {
    array[TI] = array[FI];
    return true;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t Size,
          std::size_t... T0>
void remove_even_aux(T (&array)[Size],
                     std::index_sequence<T0...>) {
    bool aux0[] = { assign<T0, 2 * T0 + 1>(array)... };
    bool aux1[] = { assign<Size / 2 + T0, Size - 1>(array)... };
}

template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
void remove_even(T (&array)[Size]) {
    remove_even_aux(array, std::make_index_sequence<Size / 2>());
}

int main() {
    int array[] = { 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    print(std::cout, array) << "\n";
    remove_even(array);
    print(std::cout, array) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If C++ algorithms are an option, I tend to prefer them by default:

```
auto *const end_A = A + (sizeof(A)/sizeof(*A));
auto *new_end = std::remove_if(
    A, end_A,
    [&A](int const& i) { return (&i - A) % 2 == 0; });

// Now "erase" the remaining elements.
std::fill(new_end, end_A, 0);
```

The `std::remove_if` algorithm simply moves the elements that do not match the predicate (in our case, test if the address is MOD(2)=0), and `std::move`s them to the end.  This is in place.  The new "end" is return, which I then indexed over and set the elements to 0.

Answer (score 0):

So if it has to be an array the solution would be like this:

```
void deleting(int A[size], int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
        A[i] = A[2 * i + 1];
    for (int i = size / 2; i < size; i++)
        A[i] = A[size / 2];
}
```

You first loop through first half of the array "moving" every second number to the front, and then you loop through the rest filling it with the last number.

Answer (score 0):

For a more versatile version of other's answers:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename InputIt, typename T>
void filter(InputIt begin, InputIt end, T const& defaultvalue)
{
    InputIt fastforward = begin;
    InputIt slowforward = begin;
    fastforward++; // starts at [1], not [0]
    while (fastforward < end)
    {
        *slowforward = *fastforward;
        ++slowforward;
        ++ ++fastforward;
    }
    while (slowforward < end) // fill with default value
    {
        *slowforward++ = defaultvalue;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[6] = {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    std::cout << "before: ";
    for (auto n : A)
        std::cout << n << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    filter(A, A+6, 1);

    std::cout << "after: ";
    for (auto n : A)
        std::cout << n << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
before: 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 
after: 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1,
```

And this works with `std::array<bool>`, `std::vector<std::string>`, `std::unordered_set<void*>::iterator`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The common way of doing this would be keeping two indices: one to the entry you're modifying and the other to the entry you intend to *process*

```
const auto size = sizeof(A) / sizeof(int);

// N.b. if size == 1 entire array is garbage
int i = 0;
for (int nv = 1; nv < size; ++i, nv += 2)
  A[i] = A[nv];
--i;
// Significative array is now [0;N/2[, fill with last now
for (int j = i + 1; j < size; ++j)
  A[j] = A[i];
```

This grants an in-place-modify fashion.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine `std::remove_if` and `std::fill` to do this

---

example code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
   int A[6] = {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

   auto endX = std::remove_if(std::begin(A),std::end(A),[&A](const int& i){return (&i-A)%2==0;});
   if(endX!=std::begin(A))//in case nothing remained, although not possible in this case
      std::fill(endX,std::end(A),*(endX-1));
   //else /*something to do if nothing remained*/

   for(auto a : A)std::cout<<a<<' ';
}
```

Comment: @cyberbisson you edit is incorrect, so I roll back it, `remove_if` return a new `end` iterator, it will at `begin` if nothing match. Since I will use `*(end-1)`, `end` should not at `begin`. And the OP didn't specify which operation to apply for this situation, so I left the else part NOP.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding what you're saying, but [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/), it states "The range between first and this iterator includes all the elements in the sequence for which pred does not return true."  `remove_if` is designed to pass its result right back into erase, so if nothing was removed, it will return `end(A)`.  If it returned `begin(A)`, then it would erase the entire container if nothing was 'removed.'  Your `fill` also doesn't make sense, because it's filling from *beyond* the end of A to whatever `remove_if` returns.

Comment: @cyberbisson sorry for the confusing, I mean *nothing is remained* when I wrote *nothing match*, I'll update it.

Comment: Ohh, so you're saying (in the algorithm) that if the `remove_if` removes *all* of it, you don't want to bother filling A.  Totally misread that one.  Thanks for clearing it up.